# react-native-dropdown-picker changing dropdown background color by condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dropdown

We are using react-native-dropdown-picker.

```js
<DropDownPicker
    items={timeList.map(item => {
        return ({
            label: item.timeslot,
            value: item.timeslot
        })
    })}
    defaultValue={timeList[0].timeslot}
    placeholder={"Select date"}
    containerStyle={styles.dropDownContainer}
    itemStyle={{ justifyContent: "flex-start" }}
    dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: colors.white }}
    dropDownMaxHeight={hp("45%")}
    onChangeItem={item => timeSelected(item.value)}
    arrowSize={30}
    arrowStyle={{ position: "absolute", right: 0 }}
    labelStyle={{
        fontSize: wp('3.5%'),
        fontFamily: constants.themeFont,
        textAlign: 'left',
        color: '#000',
        alignSelf: 'center',
    }} />
```

So the dropdown's background color has been set from 'dropDownStyle' property. I have given the color white.

Let's say, in the 'timeList' (array)variable, I have a key 'enabled' (boolean value) on every object on the array. So I want to give different background colors for different values(true/ false) of the key 'enabled'.

The 'dropDownStyle' is the common property for all the values on the dropdown. So how to change the background color based on every item attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/next/advanced/list-and-items#item-specific-styles)

```
    {
  ...
  containerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#000"
  },
  labelStyle: {
    color: "#fff"
  }
}
```